# Prerequisites for Complex Analysis by Serge Lang

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, self-learning, advice

In Serge Lang’s Complex Analysis, he says that a prerequisite is 2 years if calculus. But I’m not sure exactly what he means by this. In regards to calculus related courses, I’ve done 3 semesters of real analysis, 1 semester of (non rigorous) complex analysis, 1 semester of single variable calculus, 1 semester of multivariable calculus and 1 semester of vector calculus (as well as some ODE/PDE courses).

Is this enough calculus, or does he specifically mean that you need to do 1 full year of single variable and 1 full year of multivariable calculus?

Thanks

Comment: Don't be silly. You have more than enough.

Comment: What Serge Lang is really saying is that if you don't have a good combination of [intelligence/talent + motivation/energy] + a reasonable Calculus background, you will be frustrated.  His hidden idea is that the people who do **not** question his assertion, as you have questioned it, may be headed for frustration.  One idea is that if a Complex Analysis theorem uses a corresponding Real Analysis theorem in support, and you are not familiar with the Real Analysis theorem, it will take intelligence/motivation to scurry, simultaneously grappling with the corresponding Real Analysis theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I think I’ll go for it then